# Value cannot be null CommandBinding custom command

Tags: c#, wpf

I've just started with WPF a few days ago and have come to a problem I dont understand.

I got the following error:

> Value cannot be null. Parametername: value

The error occurs here:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="self:CustomCommands.Exit" Executed="ExitCommand_Executed" CanExecute="ExitCommand_CanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

I've of course set namespace `xmlns:self="clr-namespace:PrintMonitor"` in the xaml.

The code-behind:

```
namespace PrintMonitor
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ExitCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e != null)
                e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void ExitCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
                (
                        "Beenden",
                        "Exit",
                        typeof(CustomCommands),
                        new InputGestureCollection()
                        {
                            new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                        }
                );
    }
}
```

So why does this error occurs if I use a custom command but not if i use e.g. `Command="ApplicationCommands.New"` and how can I fix this error?

The Code is part of [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/).

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I am not able to reproduce your error based on the tutorial and the snippets provided.

Comment: Vs 2015 Enterprise V 14.0.

I should add that the project compiles and runs but the error persists

Comment: I've now created a new project and copied 1:1 and the error is gone... intellisense bug i guess!?

Comment: Could be, I remember in old versions of VS I had this error from time to time and it usually went away by restarting VS.

Comment: In VS 2017, toggling the Enable Project Code button between the Design and XAML views fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the button "Enable Project Code" Just under the designer window

[image: Enable Project Code button]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the CustomCommands to not static,

and let the MainWindow's DataContext to be CustomCommands

```
 public class CustomCommands
 {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
                (
                        "Beenden",
                        "Exit",
                        typeof(CustomCommands),
                        new InputGestureCollection()
                        {
                            new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                        }
                );
 }

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public  CustomCommands CM;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        CM = new  CustomCommands();
        this.DataContext = CM;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void ExitCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e != null)
            e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void ExitCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, then I just cleaned then built the solution and it was gone. For future reference i found that many problems with WPF using Visual Studio are just solved by clean then build, no idea why these issues happen more frequent with WPF + VS.